# How to displace the particles-js particles around a DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, css, particles.js

I'm making a site that uses [particles-js](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) as a background. I have my name in the center of the page, and the name paragraph is within a div. What I'd like to do is this: I'd like to configure particles-js so that it pushes the particles away when the go near the div, similar to the default demo on the particles-js website where the particles are pushed away around the cursor. I would normally not ask a question that involves someone writing code for me, but I have little to no understanding of the actual workings of particles-js, so this topic is a bit over my head.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should at least try to get started, and ask question when you hit a roadblock.

Comment: @Nehal I did. I did searches and tried looking through particles-js's code to see if I could find something, but it's a bit confusing for me so I came here to see if other people have done that before or knew how to.